# Is there any way to change the data of a process from another one without using shared memory?

Tags: c, linux

I am working on a fuse program, when a read() call in fuse is called, it will read the specific file A and save it to its buffer. In my case, I let fuse send a message to my program, and it retrieves data from remote server and save it to this file A, then fuse read this file to get the data.

I am wondering is there a way to let my program save the data right into the buffer of fuse, and avoid I/O operations. Does named pipe a good option? I mean does it store its data in the memory? Or could I change this buffer to a shared memory? I know how to create a shared memory, but do not know if I could convert it. It seems a privates one.

Thanks your guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh i think here you want to make some communication between two different process then the idea of **IPC(Interprocess Communication)** comes..

there are 5 ways of doing that

1 **Shared memory** permits processes to communicate by simply reading and
writing to a specified memory location.

2 **Mapped memory** is similar to shared memory, except that it is associated with a
file in the filesystem.

3 **Pipes** permit sequential communication from one process to a related process.

4 **FIFOs** are similar to pipes, except that unrelated processes can communicate
because the pipe is given a name in the filesystem.

5 **Sockets** support communication between unrelated processes even on different
computers.

i think here shared memory will be good option.

```
1> 1st declare some shared memory in your program then attache it with fuse

2> when fuse send a message then your program should get data from server 
and save it to that shared memory 

3> make some signaling methods(to avoid any race condition) so after that 
fuse can use that data
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I am wondering if I could just write into this specific buffer in fuse. But thanks again, I'll use a pipe to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write into some `mmap` of `/proc/1234/mem` where 1234 is the pid of the target process, but I don't recommend doing that (and there are certainly permission issues). And that still becomes a weird (and Linux specific) way of sharing memory. (I am not sure it should work).

But [Mr32's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8637429/841108) is more appropriate.